# How to make SKU# visible on frontend?

Tags: magento-1.9, sku

I want to make `SKU#` visible on website. I found directions to update `list.phtml` and `view.phtml`.

It says to go to `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml.`

Please advise where JAVA files are located? I have never done before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to : `app/design/frontend/{your current package}/{your current theme}/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`, `app/design/frontend/{your current package}/{your current theme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` then add this :

```
<?php echo  $this->htmlEscape($_product->getSku()) ?>
```

You don't need a java file.

Comment: I see the directory but I am not sure where to find it in Magento. @PeterSmith

Comment: Open your FTP then go `var/html/app/...` or `var/www/app/...`